# Template Friend Class: Forward Declaration or...?

Tags: c++, templates, friend-class

Suppose I have a template class that I am trying to declare as a friend class. Should I forward declare the class or give it its own template?

Example:

```
template <typename E>
class SLinkedList;
template <typename E>
class SNode {
private:
  E elem;
  SNode<E>* next;
  friend class SLinkedList<E>;
};
```

Or

```
template <typename E>
class SNode {
private:
  E elem;
  SNode<E>* next;
  template <typename T>
  friend class SLinkedList;
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first approach is probably what you want.  It will make `SLinkedList<int>` a friend of `SNode<int>`, and similar for all matching types.

Your second approach will make every `SLinkedList` a friend of every `SNode`.  This is probably not what you want as `SLinkedList<Widget>` has no business touching the private parts of an `SNode<int>`

---

A different approach I could recommend would be to make `SNode` a nested class. This is pretty common for data structures consisting of nodes:

```
template <typename E>
class SLinkedList {
    struct SNode {
        E elem;
        SNode* next;
    };
};
```

With this scheme you may as well get rid of the friend declaration and have everything in `SNode` be public, because the whole class would be private to `SLinkedList`